# Scala jobs sent via Livy to HDInsight can't see metastore

Tags: azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-hdinsight

When running scala applications via Livy in HD Insight cluster, the sqlContext I create in my application seems to not take into account the hive metastore. It throws "table not found" exception when executing some

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1").collect.foreach(println)
```

However, when doing the same thing in spark-shell, it works fine.

Do I have to specify some property somewhere?

I thought it could be a permission access so I tried to specify the user to impersonate using proxyUser parameter, but it wasn't take into account neither.

Here is the json I send to Livy:

```
{ "file":"wasb://container@storage.blob....", "className":"com.server.MyClass" }
```

Here is how I create both sc and sqlContext variables:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround for this issue. Go to Ambari and change SPARK config.
`https://<cluster endpoint>/#/main/services/SPARK/configs`

Expand Advanced spark-env, change the line that contains `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH` to:

```
 export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH:/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/*:/usr/lib/hdinsight-datalake/*:/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However I need it to be configured this way in the  creation of the cluster. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: To automate the change at cluster creation, I created a sh file with the following command : sed -i -- 's|export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH:/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/\*:/usr/lib/hdinsight-datalake/\*:/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf/hive-site.xml|export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH:/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/\*:/usr/lib/hdinsight-datalake/\*:/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf|g' /etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh and add an action script entry to the arm template.